# FFmpeg: merge 8 mono audio streams MOV file into one audio stream FLV file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, stream, flv, mov

I have a MOV file with eight mono audio streams, likely a 5.1 or 7.1 setup. I want to generate a for-web preview FLV file from it but in doing so lose the voices in the dialogue. FFmpeg is likely favoring an audio stream out of the eight that doesn't have the voices. When I researched ways to merge the audio streams, in order to bring the voices back, I lose the ability to execute my ffmpeg command entirely. Here's what I have at the moment (the introduction of the "-map 0" option rendered the command non-executable)

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i ../vmx_files/6711177.mov -map 0 -y -f flv -qmax 10
      -vf "scale=trunc(oh*a/2)*2:720" -ar 44100 -ab 64k assets/flv/6711177.flv


ffmpeg version N-69160-g1013c15 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 20 2015 09:41:10 with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)
  configuration:
  libavutil      54. 17.100 / 54. 17.100
  libavcodec     56. 20.100 / 56. 20.100
  libavformat    56. 19.100 / 56. 19.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '../vmx_files/6711177.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2015-11-24 23:00:27
  Duration: 00:01:48.34, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 229443 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores (apch / 0x68637061), yuv422p10le(bt709), 1920x1080, 220043 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 2997 tbn, 2997 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-11-24 23:00:27
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : Apple ProRes 422 (HQ)
      timecode        : 00:59:50;00
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-11-24 23:00:27
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-11-24 23:00:27
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:3(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-11-24 23:00:27
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:4(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-11-24 23:00:27
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:5(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-11-24 23:00:27
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:6(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-11-24 23:00:27
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:7(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-11-24 23:00:27
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:8(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-11-24 23:00:28
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:9(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : -0
      creation_time   : 2015-11-24 23:03:22
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:59:50;00
Data stream encoding not supported yet (only streamcopy)
```

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.

Comment: the tag ffmpeg is on ~9000 questions. didn't realize they were all off topic

Comment: there's a difference between writing programs that use ffmpeg, and simply USING ffmpeg. you're not programming, you're just using ffmpeg at the command line.

Comment: understood, i also posted this on the ffmpeg forums

Comment: Snucky, you should make a "for-web preview MP4 file" instead. This way it can be playable by either Flash or some in-Browser capability (HTML5). When you have your final working FLV then simply transcode as `ffmpeg -i yourVid.flv -c:v copy -c:a copy outVid.mp4` is almost instant as it simply replaces FLV bytes with MP4 bytes but keeps the existing codec data intact...